# Query search on model's relationship without getting the relationship

Tags: javascript, sql, bookshelf.js

I'm using BookshelfJS. I have two tables, `users`, and `books`. I want to get the list of all users who own a specific book. The returned result should just be the users who have the books; so I don't want to get anything about the books or any of the users who don't have the books.

The following code currently doesn't work:

```
var qb = function (qb) {
    qb.where('book_name', '=', 'someBookTitle');
}

new User()
    .fetchAll({withRelated: ['books', qb]}
    .then(function (users) {
        res.json(users);
    });
```

I understand how `.fetchAll` will get all users, and then the `qb` function just filters out the relationship. But how do I accomplish what I want?

Comment: Why not use `where`? [ http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-where ]

Comment: I am using `where` inside the query. The book name is part of the relation, not the original model

Comment: It looks very similar to this case: http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-belongsTo